# Symlink In Laravel 5.4 is created with artisan command. Its working on localhost but not on live server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have developed a laravel project in laravel 5.4 on xampp localhost.

as on localhost I ued `php artisan storage:link` to link `storage/app/public/images` with `public/storage` to access images. So its working 100% correctly on local host but when I uploaded it on hosting server I lost access to those images. I dont know how can I fix it. please some one help me to make it working.

Comment: have you given the permission to storage/app/public/images to access images?

Comment: if not you need to give permission i.e read,write and delete to your target folder from your cpanel

Comment: Did you use git for this? So when you pull in the project from your git repository, you still have to run `php artisan storage:link` again. Git does not commit the link to the repository.

Comment: still not solved.. when i used `php artisan storage:link` using localhost. so it created the a shortcut to `D:\xampp\htdocs\project\storage\app\public` with the name `storage`. now my project is on shared hosting and there i cant run `php artisan storage:link` command. what should i do now..?? on local host still its working as i want..??

Comment: @M.Ibrar did you get any solutions

Answer (score 0):

First delete the shortcut created from localhost (if you have uploaded it to server).

Create a blank php file (like link.php), paste the code below to it:

```
<?php
symlink('/home/**domain**/storage/app/public', '/home/**domain**/public_html/tests/storage');
```

In the above code, don't forget to replace **domain** with the name of the root folder of your domain.

Then upload the file to your public folder (like public_html).

Then on your browser search for your_domain_name/link.php

Hope it will work